# how to get month, week , day format list of next week?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i want to get the list of next week days in given format "March 12 Sunday" and then convert that is final list of week days as given below.
Here is a my current code with which i am trying to get desire output but that returns "06/12/22" format..

**Current code :**

```
const nextWeek = [...Array(7).keys()].map(days => new Date(Date.now() + 86400000 * days).toLocaleDateString('en-us', { weekday:"long", month:"short", day:"numeric"}))
        console.log("== > ",nextWeek)
```

**current output :**

```
["09/17/22", "09/18/22", "09/19/22", "09/20/22", "09/21/22", "09/22/22", "09/23/22"]
```

**first i want this output**

```
 ["Sunday, March 4", "Monday, March 4", "Tuesday, March 4", "Wednesday, March 4", "Thursday, March 4", "Friday, March 4", "Saturday, March 4"]
```

**and then final desire output is:**

```
const nextWeekdata = [

            { id: 1, name: "Sunday" ,date:21,Month:"March" },
            { id: 2, name: "Monday" ,date:22,Month:"March" },
            { id: 3, name: "Tuesday" ,date:23,Month:"March" },
            { id: 4, name: "Wednesday" ,date:24,Month:"March" },
            { id: 5, name: "Thursday" ,date:25,Month:"March" },
            { id: 6, name: "Friday" ,date:26,Month:"March" },
            { id: 7, name: "Saturday" ,date:27,Month:"March" },
          ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the range of dates for next week, break your logic into smaller chunks.

You should have three functions:

- Function that gets the date for a given day of the week; next week
- Function that gets the range of all the dates next week
- Function to map the dates to object data

```js
const getNextDay = (dayIndex) => {
  const today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate() + (dayIndex - 1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
  return today;
};

const getNextWeek = () => [...Array(7).keys()].map(getNextDay);

const nextWeek = getNextWeek().map((date, index) => ({
  id: index + 1,
  name: date.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' }),
  date: date.getDate(),
  month: date.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { month: 'long' }),
  year: date.getFullYear()
}));

console.log(nextWeek);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const nextWeek = [...Array(7).keys()].map((days) =>
  new Date(Date.now() + 86400000 * days).toLocaleDateString("en-us", {
    weekday: "long",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
  })
);
let newArray = [];
nextWeek.forEach((item, index) => {
  let data = item.split(",");
  let secondLength = data[1].length;
  newArray.push({
    id: index + 1,
    name: data[0],
    date: data[1].substring(secondLength - 2),
    month: data[1].substring(1, secondLength - 3),
  });
});
console.log("days", newArray);
```

does this work? yes

is this the right way to do it? nope

is this the easy way? for me, it is.

Comment: *is this the right way to do it? nope*, then what *would* be the right way?

Comment: well it worked and gave me desire output. but as far as concerned with the right approach then we need to of it once again. but Thank you for now. it is working.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier in my experience, the moment you have to use string methods this extensively, then you are writing long code then it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when I use your current code I get this as a result:

> (7) ['Saturday, Sep 17', 'Sunday, Sep 18', 'Monday, Sep 19', 'Tuesday, Sep 20', 'Wednesday, Sep 21', 'Thursday, Sep 22', 'Friday, Sep 23']

Which means it works as you wish; what browser are you using?

Regarding the Second Question of yours, I'd have used something such as this:

```
class weekDay {
   constructer(id, x) {
      let name = x.split(", ")[0];
      let day = x.split(", ")[1].split(" ")[1];
      let month = x.split(", ")[1].split(" ")[0];
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.day = day;
      this.month = month;
   }
}
const nextWeek = [...Array(7).keys()].map(days => new Date(Date.now() + 86400000 * days).toLocaleDateString('en-us', { weekday:"long", month:"long", day:"numeric"}))
var arr = [];
for (let i=0; i<=6; i++) {
   arr.push(new weekDay(i+1, nextWeek[i]));
}
```

This is my way of doing it, but take heed that I haven't tested it so it might have some syntax errors, if there was any, please notify me.